# QLineEdit as a modal window

Tags: qt

I have a class MyLineEdit which inhereted QLineEdit. I would like to ask whether it is possible to make my class to behave as a modal window. For example, when MyLineEdit object has the focus, it should wait for the input and in the same time to block the input to other visible windows and widgets in the same application. But the Qt documentation says that

> This property only makes sense for windows

and I don't have any other ideas how to implement this?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. You want a widget which is sort of "modal" (block other widgets), but not a separate window? How would one leave the line edit/the modal state? Sounds like quite horrible UI design unless I misunderstand the concept.

Comment: For example, let's imagine I have a widget with two line edits (one for username and one for password) and two buttons. I would like to be impossible to press buttons or to go to the password field without filling the username field. That's not exactly my case, but the logic is the same. I suggested a modal window because that was the only idea I had. In my case I cannot use a separate modal window.

Comment: Ken James: Disable the "Login"/OK button via setEnabled(false) until the username line edit is filled (one can connect to textChanged() to update the button state). Depending on the situation you should have a "Cancel" button always enabled.

Comment: In my previous comment I said that this is just an example describing the concept I need because you said: " Sounds like quite horrible UI design unless I misunderstand the concept." but my case is more complicated than a line edit with two buttons. Maybe you are right that something in my design is not as it should be. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually Frank Osterfeld, you are right. Thank you. What I find useful is to have a list as a QList<QWidget *> widgetList; and inserting every widget I need to be disabled in this list. In this way I can iterate over this list and calling setDisable(false).

Answer (score 1):

Put your `QLineEdit` in a dialog, and show it modally. Here is an example in PyQt

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(600,400)
        b = QtGui.QPushButton("Click", self)
        b.clicked.connect(self.showTextInput)

    def showTextInput(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog(self)
        dialog.resize(200,30)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(dialog)
        line = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(line)
        dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but actually in my case, my lineEdit is inheriting QLineEdit class so I am looking for a solution that I can use insight my class. Sorry for that, I will edit my question.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense what you are asking. Modal applies to a dialog blocking interaction with others. What you are suggesting is that the minute someone give your line edit focus they can never get out of it. You must raise the line edit in a modal dialog.

Comment: Actually they can go out of it if you use connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), dialog, SLOT(accept())) but in my case I cannot use a separate modal window.